# Rails 4: Upload Data Uri with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, data-uri

I'm using the [webcamnjs](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) to take pictures from webcam, and I looking a way to upload it with carrierwave. I found [this gem](https://github.com/timsly/carrierwave-data-uri) who do that.

So I have my js code to take the picture:

```
 function save_photo() {
  // actually snap photo (from preview freeze) and display it
  Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
    // display results in page
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
      '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/><br/></br>' + 
      '<a href="'+data_uri+'" target="_blank">link</a>';

    // shut down camera, stop capturing
    Webcam.reset();

  } );
```

**The question is:** How can I read the data_uri js variable and integrate that in the ruby code for upload and save it without reload the page, with ajax?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What do you need is something like that:

```
function save_photo() {
  // actually snap photo (from preview freeze) and display it
  Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
    $.ajax({
      // put a valid route
      url: '/profile/2',
      type: 'PATCH',
      data: { image: data_uri }
    })
    .done(function () {
      // display results in page
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
        '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/><br/></br>' + 
        '<a href="'+data_uri+'" target="_blank">link</a>';
    });

    // shut down camera, stop capturing
    Webcam.reset();
});
```

Comment: The images are in another model. I have a model Users has_many Pictures. How this code convert the data_uri to carrierwave upload it?